# error: object has no method "split"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, positioning

I want to fall in love with jQuery UI's positioning feature but everytime I run the attached code I get the following errors in javascript's console:

> firefox: `(b[this] || "").split is not a function`
>   chromium: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'split'

I've downloaded the full jquery-UI package and included the css, jQuery-min and jQuery-UI-min.

Not sure if I'm just using it wrong and missing a simple thing to kick of the magic. I tried to mimic [the example from the project webpage](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position) :C At least I hope the current version is not broken :C

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <link rel="styleSheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
         $( function() {

        function position( using ) {

             $("#main").position({
              of: $( "#head" ),
              my: $( "right top"),
              at: $( "right bottom")
            });
        }

        position();
    });
  </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="head" style="background-color: #F21; height: 7%">
      Menu
    </div>

    <div id="main" style="background-color: #1A9; width: 50%; height: 50%; position: absolute">
      <h1>Jules Verne</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing the wrong parameters to "my" and "at". You just need to pass a string, not a jQuery object. Do it like this instead:

```
$("#main").position({
    of: $("#head"),
    my: "right top",
    at: "right bottom"
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Z57KH/1/)**.

(updated code and jsfiddle to match question edit)

Comment: +1 and accept (in 5 minutes...) and thanks a lot. I feel like a total tard now http://i2.listal.com/image/3170280/500full.jpg thanks a lot for the help! ^^v

Comment: ;) no problem. Happens to all of us. Glad I could help.

Comment: just remarking: not sure if "middle" is a valid value though it seems to work it's not really documented at the page. just use 2 times in the source code. careful with that! :)